# How to remove cross from beneath of Marker when dragged in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How to remove that annoying cross from beneath the marker during dragging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve it is to set `raiseOnDrag: false` for marker options.

See example here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dN7R9/2/)

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for all over the google. Thanks.